# How to achieve this result in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

[image]

How to have the notch appear whenever a tab is selected in Flutter?
And how to animate the change by having the notch slide whenever another tab is selected?

Thank you for the help in advance

Comment: [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bZj_OGZRb_M&list=PLgGjX33Qsw-FIWxoI2IJf7zsHyxzuFfK5&index=59) is not exactly what you want but it may give you an idea on how to do it.

Comment: This is what you need https://pub.dev/packages/convex_bottom_bar

Comment: convex_bottom_bar doesn't really work as it's mainly used for bottom navigation bar, and this one is sideways

Comment: I guess there's a tutorial on youtube for make a sidebar like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the workaround that I can do :
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

/// This Widget is the main application widget.
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: MyStatefulWidget(),
    );
  }
}

class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  MyStatefulWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyStatefulWidgetState createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          NavigationRail(
            selectedIndex: _selectedIndex,
            onDestinationSelected: (int index) {
              setState(() {
                _selectedIndex = index;
              });
            },
            labelType: NavigationRailLabelType.selected,
            destinations: [
              NavigationRailDestination(
                icon: Text("Food"),
                label: Container(
                    width: 8,
                    height: 8,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.red,
                      shape: BoxShape.circle,
                    )),
              ),
              NavigationRailDestination(
                icon: Text("Bakery"),
                label: Container(
                    width: 8,
                    height: 8,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.red,
                      shape: BoxShape.circle,
                    )),
              ),
              NavigationRailDestination(
                icon: Text("Drinks"),
                label: Container(
                    width: 8,
                    height: 8,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.red,
                      shape: BoxShape.circle,
                    )),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          VerticalDivider(thickness: 1, width: 1),
          // This is the main content.
          Expanded(
            child: Center(
              child: Text(
                'selectedIndex: $_selectedIndex',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

You could use `NavigationRail` for Side Bar. But I'm not sure how to make the notch, anyway I hope this can help you a bit